# How to call external css from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply animation in javascript which i have declare in external css.All my html,css,javascript in only a one file with extension .html Here is my code.

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>

 @keyframes example {

 0%   {background-color: red; transform:translate(0px,0px)rotate(180deg);}
 25%   {background-color: green; transform:translate(0px,-150px);}
 50%    {background-color: blue; transform:translate(0px,-300px);}
 75%    {background-color: pink; transform:translate(0px,-455px);}
 100%   {background-color: yellow; transform:translate(0px,0px);}
 }

#1
{
 margin-top: 350px;
 margin-left: 1190px;
 animation-name: example;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 }
 </style>

 <script language="javascript">
 function abc()
  {
    var a=document.getElementById("1");
    a.style.Animation-Name="example" ;    // i have full doubt here css animation is not switching from here
  }
 </head> 
 <body>
 <a href="#" id="1" onclick="abc();" />onclick
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `.style.animationName`

Comment: # j08691 You mean this `function abc()
{
var a=document.getElementById("id6");
a.style.animationname="example"; ` it don't work

Comment: No, `animationName`. Case-sensitive. Also if you're doing this in a webkit browser you might need `webkitAnimationName`

Comment: j08691 can you point out my mistake in code.?

Comment: does an ID of `1` work? i would just toggle an attrib/class to engage the animation...

Answer (score 0):

Hey Raj I saw your post and I only modified a few things to arrive at this answer.  The webkit additions were found here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp.  They add multiple browser support.

The animate function uses a ternary operator.  I modified the size of your margins to better keep track of the animation.

There is probably a more eloquent solution for this problem but I hope this helps you out!  Have a nice day.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .standard.animate {
      margin-top: 100px;
      margin-left: 200px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: red;
      -webkit-animation-name: example;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 4s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red; transform:translate(0px,0px)rotate(180deg);}
    25%   {background-color: green; transform:translate(0px,-150px);}
    50%    {background-color: blue; transform:translate(0px,-300px);}
    75%    {background-color: pink; transform:translate(0px,-455px);}
    100%   {background-color: yellow; transform:translate(0px,0px);}
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: red; transform:translate(0px,0px)rotate(180deg);}
    25%   {background-color: green; transform:translate(0px,-150px);}
    50%    {background-color: blue; transform:translate(0px,-300px);}
    75%    {background-color: pink; transform:translate(0px,-455px);}
    100%   {background-color: yellow; transform:translate(0px,0px);}
}
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="standard">on Click</div>
  <script>

    const animateDiv = document.querySelector('.standard');

    function animate() {
      this.classList.contains('animate') ? this.classList.remove('animate') : 
      this.classList.add('animate');
    }

    animateDiv.addEventListener('click', animate);

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```